# A button Long Pressed just move the 4 Images to left ,right ,top,bottom corners then, Release the button set the images in same position-Android

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

1. I have a button, when button is Long pressed - move the Image view to left, right, top, bottom corners bit up.
2. After the button is released, return the Image view to previous position.
3. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

   **Mainactivity.java**

   ```
    floatingActionButton.setOnLongClickListener(new 
    View.OnLongClickListener() 
     {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

               Iv1.startAnimation(animFadein1);
               Iv2.startAnimation(animFadein2);
               |Iv3.startAnimation(animFadein3);
               Iv4.startAnimation(animFadein4);
               System.out.println("in PRESSED");
               return true; 
           }
       });

       floatingActionButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               switch(event.getAction()){
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rlesed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       return true; 
                   }
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
   ```

Please see the example image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlxqI.png]

topleft.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">;
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-5%"
        android:fromYDelta="-5%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="00%"
        android:zAdjustment="bottom"></translate>
</set>
```

topright.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">;
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="5%"
        android:fromYDelta="-5%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="00%"
        android:zAdjustment="bottom"></translate>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with ObjectAnimator like so:

```
val animatorSet = new AnimatorSet()
val moveDownAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, deltaY) // move down
val moveUpAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(anotherImageView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, -deltaY) // move up
...
animatorSet.playTogether(moveDownAnimator, moveUpAnimator,...);
animatorSet.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
animatorSet.start();
```

Similarly to release:

```
val releaseAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0);
```

Comment: i want those 4 images should move to top left ,top right, BottomLeft ,BottomRight corners ,not to move up and down side

Comment: It's just a matter of delta. You can count delta, based on your parent view size and view position.

Comment: can you add the code snippet for moving the image to left corner and right corner